# Fine-Uploader - Customize File Template in Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, fine-uploader

I have an angular controller for fine-uploader. I wanted to customize the file template so it shows the file name in a text-input, and since I'm using bootstrap, I just wanted to update the input's validation state on success, error, or alert.

Here's my controller:

```
app.controller('templateBuilderUpload', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, api) {
var manualuploader = $('#manual-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
  request: {
    endpoint: 'api/Template/UploadFile'
  },
  autoUpload: false,
  text: {
    uploadButton: '<input type="submit" value="Browse" class="btn btn-mini span2">'
  },
  validation: {
      allowedExtensions: ['pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'tif', 'tiff']
    },
  multiple: false
})

manualuploader.on('complete', function(id, name, response, xhr) {
    //Pull out the id, and redirect to /build/
    if (typeof xhr.newTemplates != 'undefined') {
        var template = xhr.newTemplates[0];

        //Save Template Name
        template.Name = $scope.templateName;
        api.post('/api/Template/Save/', template, function() {
            //Redirect
            $location.path('/templateBuilder/build/' + template.Id);
            $scope.safeApply();
        });
    }
});

$scope.errors = [];

$scope.triggerUpload = function() {

    manualuploader.fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
}
});
```

I have tried adding `fileTemplate:` and then including my desired html. It hasn't succeeded, and displays nothing at all in fact. `template` however, does work.

Also, I don't know how to go about updating the validation state of the input.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you are attempting to do here.  First off, why are you using a submit button as your upload button?  Second, where is the "text input" you speak of?  It doesn't exist anywhere in the code you have included in your question.  Third, why are you expecting a "newTemplates" property to exist on the `XMLHttpRequest` object?  I suspect there are a lot of issues with your code, and perhaps I can help more if you would provide a much more comprehensive description of your app and supported workflow.

Comment: Also, your `complete` handler is wrong.  All jQuery event handlers have an `event` parameter passed as the first argument.  This is covered in the [Fine Uploader jQuery plug-in documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/jquery.html).

Comment: ...and there is no `file-template` option.  It's `fileTemplate`.

Comment: typo, I was using `fileTemplate`. I didn't write all the code, agreed we could do better with the browse button and I will fix it. The XHR object is there due to a requirement of our implementation.

Comment: Before I posted the question I hadn't seen this: http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/styling.html I may be able to get some answers this way.

Comment: There will never by a `newTemplates` property on the XHR object.  Why are you expecting this to exist?

Comment: we call the uploaded documents `templates` on our backend. It's a variable name for our object. It's just a coincidence in terms of naming similarities.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36571/discussion-between-frankv-and-ray-nicholus)

Comment: Mark, if you see this, we discussed and probably resolved this for the most part in chat.  Click on the chat link for more details.  Frank is going to update this case with an answer when he can.

Comment: Can you add your resolution as an answer frankV?

Comment: Yes, will do once I get it cleaned up.

Comment: If you are looking for an alternative angular file upload you might wanna have a look at https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload which supports upload/drag&drop and progress lightweight and simple code.